# Why is linking to syslinux.com forbidden?

Tags: support, specific-question

The other day, I tried linking to [SYSLINUX](http://www.syslinux.com) and the editor told me that's forbidden.

Why?

Eventually, I linked to one of the pages under that Domain (EXTLINUX) and things were fine.

Comment: I just tried it on the main site, it works fine, and you seem to have linked to it here. What error did you get?